# Example of $U \subseteq V$ such that $V$ is infinite-dimensional and $U^0 = V'$ but $U \neq \{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I am working through Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, where he uses the notation $U^0$ for the annihilator subspace of the dual space $V'$ such that if $\varphi \in U^0$, then $U \subseteq \text{null}(\varphi)$.  Note that it is true that if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $U^0 = V'$ implies that $U = \{0\}$.  However, I am curious to find an example when $V$ is not finite-dimensional where $U$ needs not be equal to $\{0\}$.  Thank you in advance for your help!

PS - if there is a proof that $U = \{0\}$ if $U^0 = V'$ when $V$ is infinite dimensional, then I would be interested in that too!

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142904/a-problem-with-annihilators-in-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces

Comment: Thank you for the link - I might need to review it more, but could you provide a concrete example for my above question?